# Regular expression to get the following in python

Tags: python, regex, file, parsing

I'm parsing this file internet.test it has multiple entries some of them are:

```
Jun 15 16:26:33 dnsmasq[1979]: query[AAAA] play.google.com from 192.168.1.11
Jun 15 16:27:13 dnsmasq[1979]: forwarded play.google.com to 8.8.8.8
Jun 15 16:27:45 dnsmasq[1979]: reply play.google.com is 2404:6800:4007:810::200e
```

I want to fetch the date and time (for ex: from line 1 Jun 15 16:26:33, from line 2 Jun 15 16:27:13 and from line 3 Jun 15 16:27:45) and store it in a list (ex: Dates= ['Jun 15 16:26:33','Jun 15 16:27:13','Jun 15 16:27:45']).

I Tried taking the first 14 elements from each line as follows but it did not work.

```
@staticmethod
def getDate():
    Dates = []
    date = ''
    with open("internet.test", "r") as file:
        for line in file:
            for i in range(15):
                date += line[i]
            Dates.append(date)
        return display(Dates)
```

Is it possible to fetch and store the date and time with regular expression?

Comment: Try using `^\w{3}\s\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}` as shown [here](https://regex101.com/r/zIyfrw/1) .

Comment: What about using `.split(" ")` and loop each element ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need regex at all, cutting the line at 14 characters is easy with `line[:15]` and your whole loop can be simplified to 1 line of code with some list comprehension:

```
with open("internet.test", "r") as file:
    return display([line[:15] for line in file])
```

Or with two steps, to make it more explicit and readable:

```
with open("internet.test", "r") as file:
    Dates = [line[:15] for line in file]
return display(Dates)
```

Comment: its not working.. the output is: Dates =['u','u','u','u'... and so on]

Comment: if the contents of the text file are as you said, that's impossible. manually open the file and correct your question to display the read data inside of it

Comment: sorry, it was my mistake in printing the code snippet that you suggested worked! thank you...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `^\w{3}\s\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}` to match your dates. Live regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/zIyfrw/1).

```
import re
dates = []
with open("internet.test","r") as content_file:
    for line in content_file:
        m = re.search('^\w{3}\s\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}',line)
        dates.append(m.group(0))

dates = 
['Jun 15 16:26:33', 'Jun 15 16:27:13', 'Jun 15 16:27:45']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def dates_from_file(f):
    with open(f) as file:
        for l in file:
            yield l[0:16]

dates = [d for d in dates_from_file("internet.test")]
print(dates)
```